# How to make Apache Camel Kafka component work with brokers that are exposed through zookeper only

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-zookeeper

We currently can't rely on specifying the Kafka brokers list to the app, as they are ephemeral k8s pods, and at any time can be stopped and recreated with newer IPs. While for some reason after getting connected to the Kafka broker, the apache Camel Kafka producer library keeps the IPs of the brokers and try to send data to specific IP each time. So on the Kafka broker nodes recreation those IPs become outdated.

So we need to connect to Zookeper (as the k8s service like `kafka-zookeper:2181`) that will provide the actual data on living broker nodes. But the Apache Camel documentation doesn't [include zookeper url](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html) in the connection details now. How to provide it correctly?

Just replacing the brokers URL with Zookeper doesn't help:

```
kafka://ESP_01.Handle_Movement?brokers=localhost:2181
```

It causes the below stacktraces:

```
0:29:11.092 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:517)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:444)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
00:29:11.092 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
00:29:11.092 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:2181 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
00:29:11.092 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.producer.internals.Sender - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Disconnect from null while trying to send request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1). Going to back off and retry.
```

So how Apache Camel Kafka component can attach to zookeeper to retrieve the brokers urls from it?

Comment: Use a k8s service. Use a headless service.

Comment: @Namphibian and what we make a bootstrap stinrg here? Kafka client extect a list of specific ID, i,.e. pods. But instead we have a single service url like kafka:9092 that balacnes broker behind it. Is it ok to specify it instead of the list of pods?

Comment: A headless service will return a list of IP addresses.